# is there a way to apply css or java script in a "web view" in android?

Tags: javascript, android, css

here is the code i used to extract source code of a website and i need to extract some part of it, and show it in an android webview.

in this code i just saved the source in a string named"sourcecode" and i want to load this html code into my web view; it does that work but it doesn't applying any css or java script.

is there a way to apply them?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    WebView wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    final String mimetype = "text/html";
    final String encoding = "UTF-8";
    String html="<H2>Problme with loading Page</H2>";

            //here i used the method "getUrlSource()" that i wrote myself   
    String sourceCode ="";
    try {
        sourceCode = getUrlSource("http://www.nerkh.co");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        wb.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, mimetype, encoding, "");
    }

    wb.loadData(sourceCode, mimetype, encoding);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled javascript for your webview using

`webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` ?

Css and javascript should work just find for cached webpages.
You might need internet connection for the referenced css/js files to be loaded though.
I suspect there is probably something wrong with the method `getUrlSource`.

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to apply the original websites css?

Comment: Yes i have enabled that too, it doesn't work. the method getUrlSource is tested well and it returns the website source code.I have internet connections